# 301 Permanent Redirect

Tags: php, redirect, http-status-code-301

a website has used a "301 permanent redirect" to my site is there a way i can set code that detects this and displays a page when my website is accessed through this?

Does anyone have any idea about this?

Comment: What is your server side language ?

Comment: No. Your site will only ever see a 'GET' request come in from the client browser. The 301 redirect is done directly between that other site and the client browser, and will never appear on your own site.

Comment: If you want to display a specific page for a 301 redirect why not just point the 301 redirect to that page instead?

Comment: Hi Manse, My server side language is php

Comment: Hi JaredPar, I have not set the 301 redirect up someone else has to point to my site, so i would like to basically inform them that the url they entered is not the "official one" so to speak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get only a referer. I think you will not be able to get the http status code on server which the client gets during last request.

So my answer is NO, you cannot get the 301 status code on your server.

But you can do a little of needed magic with referer variable.

e.g. in PHP you can read this:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

Comment: In 301 redirect Referer is not passed

Comment: I know the URLs of the websites that are using the 301 to my site if that helps?

Comment: Don't use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];`.  Even PHP's documentation says it can't be systematically trusted.

Comment: Yes, if you know it, you can check if it's same as referer and behave accordingly.

But @Jamie is right, you cannot 100% trust it. But at least something, than nothing.

Comment: @Jamie, it can't be used for security.  It can be used for analytics.

Comment: You can't use the referer, because 301 redirects don't change it.

Answer (score 0):

Not much you can do. If you were doing the 301, you could set the referrer to the querystring. But since you're not, you can only grab what the request has given you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using PHP's `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` to track the source URL from where your visitor comes from.  I think it's a bit dodgy though and might not yield the same result in all browsers.  Even [PHP's documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) says 'it cannot really be trusted'.

Why do you have to use .htaccess for the redirect?  You could do something like this:

Site A's index.php:

```
header("Location: http://siteb.com/?ref=".urlencode('http://sitea.com');
```

Site B's index.php:

```
if(isset($_GET['ref']))
{
   if($_GET['ref']=='http://sitea.com')
   {
      // Do something
   }
}
```

**Edit:**

If you can't edit Site A's code or server settings, try using:

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']=='http://sitea.com')
{
   // Do something
}
```

Comment: I have not set the 301 redirect up someone else has to point to my site, so i would like to basically inform them that the url they entered is not the "official one" so to speak

Comment: i tried 

<?php
 if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']=='http://unwanted-website.com')
 {
   header( 'Location: http://www.mysite.com/please_use_this_url.php' ) ;
 }
 ?>

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you can implement this in PHP:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'redirectedsite.com') !== false) {
    // Display a custom page or perform any desired actions
    echo 'This page was accessed through a 301 redirect from redirectedsite.com';
} else {
    // Regular website content
    echo 'Welcome to our website!';
}
```

In this example, $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] contains the value of the "Referer" header. The code checks if the referer URL contains "redirectedsite.com" (you can replace it with the actual domain that is redirecting to your site).

If it does, you can display a custom page or perform any other actions. Otherwise, the regular website content is displayed.